# How to disable Visual Studio Code from removing spaces in PHP on save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to disable Visual Studio Code from removing spaces in PHP on save?
For example, Wordpress standard is to have a space which VScode will remove on save

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );  // Before save
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');    // After save
```

I believe I would need to define it in User settings (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings), but how can I find out the name of this setting so that it can be overriden, if it exists?

```
  "[php]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true, // I don't want to turn it off
    "editor.???": false
  }
```

Comment: I understand you want to configure the PHP formatter but, as far as I know, Visual Studio Code does not bundle a PHP formatter. You must have an extension that takes care of that—whether it can be done depends on such extension.

Comment: Do you need help to determine what PHP extensions you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
"editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false
```

Comment: for me `\Infusionsoft\Http\HttpException $e`  becomes `\Infusionsoft\Http\HttpException$e` I want to remove trailing spaces otherwise. Do you know how to disable this behavior. Its in laravel only